# torch: what are the differences between using net:cuda() and using cudnn.somemodules?

Tags: python, torch

I'm wondering what the differences are between:

1. using `net:cuda()` after making a neural net:

```
local net = nn.Sequential()
net:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(3, 8, 5, 5))
net:add(nn.View(8*20*20))
net:add(nn.Linear(8*20*20, 10))
net:add(nn.LogSoftMax())
net:cuda()
```

2. using `cudnn.somemodules` on the way completing a neural net:

```
local net = nn.Sequential()
net:add(cudnn.SpatialConvolution(3, 8, 5, 5))
net:add(cudnn.View(8*20*20))
net:add(cudnn.Linear(8*20*20, 10))
net:add(cudnn.LogSoftMax())
```

Answer (score 0):

`:cuda()` is to use GPU

`cudnn.xxx` is to use some optimation for GPU model, so after adding it the training will be faster than only use cuda.

There is an introduction for `cudnn`: [Accelerate Machine Learning with the cuDNN Deep Neural Network Library](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/accelerate-machine-learning-cudnn-deep-neural-network-library/)

Answer (score 0):

`cuda()` is a call to move tensors to the GPU for faster computation of operations.

`cudnn` is a library of cuda optimised modules, analogous to `nn`. If working on a GPU, using the `cudnn` analgues will be faster, but your code will not be portable to a CPU device:

> NVIDIA CUDA Deep Neural Network (cuDNN) is a GPU-accelerated library of primitives for deep neural networks. It provides highly tuned implementations of routines arising frequently in DNN applications. These release notes describe the key features, software enhancements and improvements, and known issues for the cuDNN 8.1.1 and earlier releases.